# TypeError: msgs.forEach is not a function

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a transcript button, but when it run gives me the error:

> TypeError: msgs.forEach is not a function

I don't know how to resolve it.. Someone know a solution?
I tried everything and search very much but don't find nothing

````js
if (interaction.customId === 'trs') {
            let messageCollection = new Collection();
            let channelMessages = await interaction.channel.messages.fetch({
                limit: 100
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    
            messageCollection = messageCollection.concat(channelMessages);
    
            while(channelMessages.size === 100) {
                let lastMessageId = channelMessages.lastKey();
                channelMessages = await interaction.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100, before: lastMessageId }).catch(err => console.log(err));
                if(channelMessages)
                    messageCollection = messageCollection.concat(channelMessages);
            }
            let msgs = messageCollection.array().reverse();
            let data = await fs.readFile('./template.html', 'utf8').catch(err => console.log(err));
            if(data) {
                await fs.writeFile(`${interaction.channel.name}.html`, data).catch(err => console.log(err));
                let guildElement = document.createElement('div');
                let guildText = document.createTextNode(interaction.guild.name);
                let guildImg = document.createElement('img');
                guildImg.setAttribute('src', interaction.guild.iconURL);
                guildImg.setAttribute('width', '150');
                guildElement.appendChild(guildImg);
                guildElement.appendChild(guildText);
                console.log(guildElement.outerHTML);
                await fs.appendFile(`${interaction.channel.name}.html`, guildElement.outerHTML).catch(err => console.log(err));
    
                msgs.forEach(async msg => {
                    let parentContainer = document.createElement("div");
                    parentContainer.className = "parent-container";
    
                    let avatarDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    avatarDiv.className = "avatar-container";
                    let img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.setAttribute('src', msg.author.displayAvatarURL);
                    img.className = "avatar";
                    avatarDiv.appendChild(img);
    
                    parentContainer.appendChild(avatarDiv);
    
                    let messageContainer = document.createElement('div');
                    messageContainer.className = "message-container";
    
                    let nameElement = document.createElement("span");
                    let name = document.createTextNode(msg.author.tag + " " + msg.createdAt.toDateString() + " " + msg.createdAt.toLocaleTimeString() + " EST");
                    nameElement.appendChild(name);
                    messageContainer.append(nameElement);
    
                    if(msg.content.startsWith("```")) {
                        let m = msg.content.replace(/```/g, "");
                        let codeNode = document.createElement("code");
                        let textNode =  document.createTextNode(m);
                        codeNode.appendChild(textNode);
                        messageContainer.appendChild(codeNode);
                    }
                    else {
                        let msgNode = document.createElement('span');
                        let textNode = document.createTextNode(msg.content);
                        msgNode.append(textNode);
                        messageContainer.appendChild(msgNode);
                    }
                    parentContainer.appendChild(messageContainer);
                    await fs.appendFile(`${interaction.channel.name}.html`, parentContainer.outerHTML).catch(err => console.log(err));
                })
                client.channels.cache.get('886342088864698408').send({
                    files:[`./${interaction.channel.name}.html`]
                })
                interaction.channel.send({
                    content: 'Ticket transcrito e logado no chat <#886342088864698408>...'
                })
            }
        }
````

Comment: try map (msgs || []).map()

Comment: Could you send me an example?

Comment: Ok I will, but could you send me first the whole of json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Discord.JS version 13.0.0 or higher `messageCollection.array()` will not work. Try using `[...messageCollection.values()]`

Example:

```js
let msgs = [...messageCollection.values()].reverse();
```

Discord.JS [Guide for Collections](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html#collections)